# Retrieving data from database #2

Tags: c#, dataset, sql-server-ce, dataadapter

I have the below command to Insert(Name,Family,Address) value in my Table ( ID,Name,Family,Address)
I'm using Data Set and Data Adapter

```
 stdDataSetTableAdapters.studentTableAdapter da = new stdDataSetTableAdapters.studentTableAdapter();
 da.InsertCard("Albert", "Alexis","No4.London");
```

It work and it add the new row of data in my database :
but here is a problem after inserting i want to Display something like that : the ID(primary key ) and one Message.

```
Display(ID +"Record Successfully Added ")
```

how i can populate ID of added record in my Display?

P.S: i'm using Sql Ce and queries i'm using Adapter to generate them and call them

Comment: Does 'id = da.InsertCard("Albert", "Alexis","No4.London");' compile and return a value ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example

```
INSERT INTO Employee (EmpName,Emp_level,Emp_Sal) VALUES ('Chris', 25B, 54000);

SELECT Emp_id FROM jobs Employee Emp_id = @@IDENTITY;
```

for More info see this [Identity(SQl Authority)](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

and this [Identity(MSDN))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

as an alternative solution to Identity one could use MAX() as well
a simple syntax would be like 
           `SELECT MAX(Emp_id) FROM Employee ;`
Hope this Helps

Comment: it gives me the first ID not the latest!

Comment: Use SCOPE_IDENTITY instead of @@IDENTITY

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() isn't supported in SQL CE

Comment: i have this Query : Select ID From studentTable; Where should i put IDentity?

Comment: if you are inserting more than one row, then MAX(ID) will give only one record.

Comment: yes Max will give you the last record Added but make sure you add Top(x) otherwise will list you all the numbers!

Answer (score 0):

please try the following Queries it may help you,

```
SELECT Top1 Emp_id FROM jobs Employee Emp_id = @@IDENTITY; 

SELECT Max Emp_id FROM jobs Employee Emp_id = @@IDENTITY;
```

Comment: Was it necessary to edit @Sankar !?!? i was just giving him a tip. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Mr.CodeBrain i have edited to make sure that your message has to be reached in a clear manner for all

Comment: Guys How can i Combine @@IDENTITY and INSERT Commend Together?           Is there any way?